# Can tests be built in release mode using Cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm using `cargo build --release` to build my project in release configuration and `cargo test` to build and run my tests.

However, I'd like to also build my tests in release mode; can this be done using cargo?

Comment: @ViktorDahl Thanks, but it's not really what I'm after: I was hoping to be able to change the configuration with which tests are built via some command line arg passed to cargo.

Comment: To satisfy my own curiosity, why do you want to do this? The main reason I can think is for running profiling tests, but those are already built with optimization.

Comment: I'm used to C++ and found that some issues were only reproducible using release code.  They were always horrible to debug, but running tests in release (or preferably RelWIthDebInfo) was often invaluable.  I don't have a need yet, but I'm anticipating one :)

Comment: @rubenvb I'll take the bait :) I disagree - often the issues were down to timing (things running significantly faster in release obviously) or code within `#ifdef NDEBUG` blocks containing bugs.

Comment: optimized code can have problems because of CPU bugs, OS bugs, library bugs, LLVM bugs, assembler bugs, linker bugs, etc etc. the code that goes out to customers should be the same code that passes test.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`cargo test --release` exists, but it is slightly different than just enabling optimizations. For example, debug assertions become disabled.

You can also set `opt-level` in [the `[profile.test]` section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-profile-sections) of your Cargo.toml, [as Viktor Dahl suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29818084/can-tests-be-built-in-release-mode-using-cargo#comment47769532_29818084).