# How to compile and run an optimized Rust program with overflow checking enabled

Tags: rust, compiler-optimization, integer-overflow

I'm writing a program that's quite compute heavy, and it's annoyingly slow to run in debug mode.

My program is also plagued by integer overflows, because I'm reading data from `u8` arrays and `u8` type spreads to unexpected places via type inference, and Rust prefers to overflow rather than to promote integers to larger types.

Building in release mode disables overflow checks:

```
cargo run --release
```

How can I build Rust executable with optimizations *and* runtime overflow checks enabled as well?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can compile in release mode [with overflow checks enabled](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-profile-sections):

```
[profile.release]
overflow-checks = true
```

This passes `-C overflow-checks=true` to the compiler. In earlier versions of Rust, `overflow-checks` was part of the `debug-assertions` switch, so you may need to use that in certain cases.

Other times, the easiest thing might be to [build in test or dev mode with optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29818084/155423):

```
[profile.dev]
opt-level = 3
```

Comment: Note: to get a good speed-up but still have meaningful stacktraces you might want to use `opt-level = 1` only. Each function body will get optimized, however in general there is no (or little) inlining. Of course it's not as fast...

Comment: For inlining there's `#[inline(never)]` and `#[inline(always)]` (of course use carefully only if you notice compiler doesn't do a good job, because overuse of these attributes can backfire).