# How to get a release build with debugging information when using cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

The following command

```
$ cargo build
```

produces a **non-optimized** build **with** debugging information. On the contrary,

```
$ cargo build --release
```

produces an **optimized** build **without** debugging information.

Is there a way of producing an **optimized** build **with** debugging information? I need this to get meaningful profiling information.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

As of [Rust 1.57](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.57.0/RELEASES.md#cargo), Cargo now allows for [*custom profiles*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#custom-profiles). This allows you to define your own profile that adds debug information:

```
[profile.release-with-debug]
inherits = "release"
debug = true
```

You can then use that profile when building:

```
% cargo build --profile=release-with-debug
   Compiling buggin v0.1.0 (/tmp/buggin)
    Finished release-with-debug [optimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.48s
```

Prior to this version, or if you **always** wanted to have debugging information, you can modify the `release` [*profile*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html) to include debugging symbols:

```
[profile.release]
debug = true
```

Note that the `release` profile and the `bench` profile differ.

See also

- [Can tests be built in release mode using Cargo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29818084/155423)
- [How to compile and run an optimized Rust program with overflow checking enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34054669/155423)
- [Does Cargo support custom profiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41920192/155423)

Or basically any of the top search results for "rust profiling":

- [Rust Profiling with Instruments and FlameGraph on OSX: CPU/Time](http://carol-nichols.com/2015/12/09/rust-profiling-on-osx-cpu-time/)
- [Profiling Rust applications on Linux](https://llogiq.github.io/2015/07/15/profiling.html)
- [Profiling rust code with callgrind](https://web.archive.org/web/20170508162645/https://shunyata.github.io/2015/10/01/profiling-rust/)

Comment: The last link (profiling rust code with callgrind) seems to be dead. I could only find this related [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3n5ann/profiling_rust_code_with_callgrind/), which contains the same dead link.

Comment: This actually produces a fat binary, is there a way of producing the debugging symbols but yet being able to have a thin binary. I have a 9MB .a file and this setting takes it to 40MB

Comment: @Pacu that's not related to this question. Splitting debug info to a separate location is platform-specific. See [Will debug symbols affect the performance in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62998579/155423)

Comment: Another way to set the same parameter is through the `CARGO_PROFILE_RELEASE_DEBUG` environment variable. You can set that to "true".

Answer (score 90):

Another option that I found that does not require changing `Cargo.toml` is to use the [`RUSTFLAGS`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html) environment variable:

```
$ RUSTFLAGS=-g cargo build --release
```