# Does Cargo support custom profiles?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I often want to compile in release mode with `debug = true` so that I can read the generated assembly a bit easier. I am currently doing this:

```
[profile.release]
debug = true
```

but I don't want any debug symbols in my final release build. I'd like to do something like:

```
[profile.custom]
debug = true
opt-level = 3
rpath = false
lto = true
debug-assertions = false
codegen-units = 1
panic = 'unwind'
```

And then run

```
cargo build --custom
```

I've read [the documentation](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-profile-sections) to no avail.

Comment: You can create a custom Cargo.toml and use it like this: `cargo build --manifest-path ./Cargo-custom.toml`. But it requires you specify dependencies in both files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Cargo support custom profiles?

No, stable releases of Cargo do not support this. It is available as an [*unstable* nightly feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/6988).

If you are using a nightly version of Cargo, you can create custom profiles in your Cargo.toml:

```
cargo-features = ["named-profiles"]

[profile.release-lto]
inherits = "release"
lto = true
```

And then use them:

```
cargo +nightly build --profile release-lto -Z unstable-options
```

Answer (score 11):

As of [Rust v1.57.0](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/12/02/Rust-1.57.0.html), the [custom profiles feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#custom-profiles) is now stable.

Add a profile section, specify a base profile to inherit from, and tweak as you see fit:

```ini
[profile.production]
inherits = "release"
lto = true
```

Specify the profile to use via the `--profile <name>` flag to cargo.