# Unable to trace an error from the backtrace caused by Serde in a Rust app

Tags: linux, rust

I have a Rust web on a remote server which I run as:

```
  RUST_BACKTRACE=1 nohup  /home/my_user/app123 &
```

When it goes down and I check nohup.log, I see only this:

```
04:52:22 [WARN] unexpected chunk when body cannot write
04:52:23 [WARN] unexpected chunk when body cannot write
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ErrorImpl { code: EofWhileParsingValue, line: 1, column: 0 }', /checkout/src/libcore/result.rs:906:4
stack backtrace:
   0: <std::time::Instant as core::fmt::Debug>::fmt
   1: <std::time::Instant as core::fmt::Debug>::fmt
   2: <std::time::Instant as core::fmt::Debug>::fmt
   3: <std::time::Instant as core::fmt::Debug>::fmt
   4: <std::time::Instant as core::fmt::Debug>::fmt
   5: <std::time::Instant as core::fmt::Debug>::fmt
   6: <std::time::Instant as core::fmt::Debug>::fmt
   7: <std::time::Instant as core::fmt::Debug>::fmt
   8: <core::cell::BorrowMutError as core::fmt::Debug>::fmt
   9: 
  10: 
  11: 
  12: 
  13: <hyper::version::HttpVersion as core::fmt::Debug>::fmt
  14: 
  15: <std::time::duration::Duration as core::fmt::Debug>::fmt
  16: <std::time::Instant as core::fmt::Debug>::fmt
  17: 
  18: <unknown>
```

How can I trace the error? It's something related to Serde JSON, but what exactly? There are many places in my app where it could occur.

Comment: Why are 9, 10, ... empty? 
Also without any code, we can't do anything. Can you provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't any line numbers in your stack backtrace so the binary running on your server must have been built without debug symbols. As described in [How to get a release build with debugging information when using cargo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38803760/155423), add the following section to `Cargo.toml` of your main binary:

```
[profile.release]
debug = true
```

This will include filename and line number information in the binary that can be printed when a panic occurs, making your stack backtraces more useful in the future.

> `ErrorImpl { code: EofWhileParsingValue, line: 1, column: 0 }`

For now, the best we can tell without a backtrace is that you tried to parse an empty JSON string. For example the following triggers the same error.

```
extern crate serde_json;

fn main() {
    let _: u64 = serde_json::from_str("").unwrap();
}
```

As a reminder, `Result::unwrap()` is not an appropriate way to handle errors in a production application. ;-)

Comment: `debug = true` --> then why not to use just "cargo build" instead of  "cargo build --release"?

Comment: @jerry because then you get no optimizations whatsoever. Not a good idea for a production deployment.