# cargo-flamegraph only showing `[main]` for most function names

Tags: rust, profiling, flamegraph

I'm trying to profile my Rust project by running a binary using cargo-flamegraph. But it is not showing function name for most of the functions. Instead it is showing `[main]`. Some functions which I believe are system calls are still shown.

My configuration is -

```
Ubuntu 22.04
perf version 6.2.13
rustc 1.74.0-nightly (84a9f4c6e 2023-08-29)
flamegraph 0.6.3
```

I've follow the instructions in cargo-flamegraph and run it like this.

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.perf_event_paranoid=-1
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict
CARGO_PROFILE_RELEASE_DEBUG=true cargo flamegraph --bin main
```

However in the final output the function names in my library are not shown. They are replaced by `[main]`.

[image: flame graph]

Comment: What are the release settings in your `Cargo.toml`?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803760/how-to-get-a-release-build-with-debugging-information-when-using-cargo) might be relevant.

Comment: The `CARGO_PROFILE_RELEASE_DEBUG=true` is supposed to achieve the same thing. But to check I also tried by setting `debug = true` in the release profile. It still doesn't show the function names.

Comment: I even tried running with `RUSTFLAGS=-g` as suggested by one of the linked answers but it doesn't help.

Comment: So after trying out options in some other discussions, setting `strip = false` and `debug = true` in `Cargo.toml` finally worked.